# Build information in server group

Tags: spinnaker

The *Clusters*-tab in the Spinnaker web UI shows my Server Groups and their deployment version *(V000 ... Vn)*. Next to the deployment version, some build information is displayed, which in my Spinnaker instance is always *(No build info)*.

Is there a way to add some build info, for example a Git commit/tag or Docker tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the build info is based on the jenkins build information. It derives this information from the ami tags `appversion` and `build_host` to link back to jenkins. `appversion` has to follow a defined schema, see [this comment in the Rosco source code](https://github.com/spinnaker/rosco/blob/552963976237a0e33efba089d850a1bd1a494fd7/rosco-core/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/rosco/providers/util/PackageNameConverter.groovy#L107) for example.

You cannot customize these values at this point, but a pull request is welcome

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the two tags, `appversion` and `build_host`, to my AWS AMIs using a self-written Packer template. The tags are visible in the EC2 Management Console, but still the _Clusters_-section of my Spinnaker-UI shows "_No build info_". Do the tags have to follow a particular format?

Comment: The build_host is just the url to your Jenkins master, but the appversion needs to end with the job name and build number. See this example in the rosco source code - 'subscriberha-1.0.0-h150.586499/WE-WAPP-subscriberha/150'
( https://github.com/spinnaker/rosco/blob/552963976237a0e33efba089d850a1bd1a494fd7/rosco-core/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/rosco/providers/util/PackageNameConverter.groovy#L107 ).

Comment: Works out fine now: I can see the build number that links to the corresponding Jenkins build page. Thanks, Tomas, for the help.